# Эффект искажения, параллакс?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, parallax

Как сделать такой же эффект как [здесь](https://www.videinfra.com/)? Особенно видно на слайде "loftec"?

Попробовал сделать подобное, но у меня при наклоне картинки видно белый фон, а у них ощущение, что картинка огромная и по ней курсор ходит.

```js
$('.test').tilt({
  maxTilt: 2,
  perspective: 500,
});
```

```css
.test {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: url(https://i.ytimg.com/vi/oZa_djYJr4E/maxresdefault.jpg);
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tilt.js/1.2.1/tilt.jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Если коротко, то картинку нужно сделать больше, чем 100% ширины. Например, задав ширину 200% или использовать transfrom scale (например, 1.5). Тогда не будет "засветов по сторонам".

Comment: Я пробовал scale, действительно засветов нет, но как только убираешь курсор с картинки scale слетает на 1 и остается.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Создаем контейнер для трансформируемого блока
2. Ставим этому контейнеру transform: scale(...), потому как плагин tilt трансформирует сам этот объект переназначая инлайново значения transform
3. Самому блоку (если это бэкграунд) ставим background-size: cover
4. Находим нужного качества и размера картинку, которая всё это будет терпеть
5. Чтобы эффект параллакса в Tilt не слетал, добавляем параметр reset: false

```js
$('.test').tilt({
  maxTilt: 2,
  perspective: 500,
  reset: false //Не возвращает параллакс на исходное "нулевое" значение
});
```

```css
.test-container {
 transform: scale(1.35);
}
.test {
  height: 100vh;
  max-width: 100%;
  background: url(https://i.ytimg.com/vi/oZa_djYJr4E/maxresdefault.jpg);
 background-size: cover
}
```

```html
<div class="test-container">
 <div class="test"></div>
</div>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tilt.js/1.2.1/tilt.jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

в оригинале они "балуются" трансформацией, которая меняется исходя из положения курсора.

```
transform: rotateX(6.77007deg) rotateY(-1.5225deg) translateZ(-15vw) scale(1.4);
```